# TinyMCE extended_valid_elements doesn't seem to do it

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I want TinyMCE to allow attributes like **style** and **class** on images but i can't really get it to work. I've read through the documentation, as well as on the net but can't find a solution.

The problem is that the 'extended_valid_elements' command doesn't do the job. Everytime I press "save" in the editor it just ignores the **style** and **class** attribute. I just wonder if someone has had the same problem?

I have a TinyMCE setup that looks like following (Everything works fine, but not the **extended_valid_elements**) :

```
$('textarea.editor').tinymce({
    // Location of TinyMCE script
    script_url : '/assets/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
    height : 400,
    width : 665,

    extended_valid_elements : "img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name|style]",

    // General options
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,imagemanager",

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,insertimage",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,

    relative_urls : false,
    skin : "o2k7",
    skin_variant : "silver",

    // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
    //content_css : "/assets/css/styles-common.css",

    // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
    template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
    external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
    external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
    media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

    // Replace values for the template plugin
    template_replace_values : {
        username : "Some User",
        staffid : "991234"
    }
});
```

Thank you!

/Jens

Comment: What version are you using? It might not be relevant but I had a lot of problems with `extended_valid_elements` in 3.4 (having to remove it in the end in order to get the rest of my app to work!)

Comment: Im using the latest version (3.4.3.1) of TinyMCE. I have also tried an older one (3.3.9.4). Same problem for both though... I can't seem to find older versions for download on their site for testing.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a tinymce version before 3.4 this feature4 is in the Doku but is deactivated since 3.3 . In this case i suggest you use the latest version.

Comment: Im using the latest version of TinyMCE, have also tried latest version of the 3.3.x series. Same problem :/

I think it has something to do with the 'style' attribute itself. The extended_valid_elements seems to work for e.g. 'class'. In some way the style attribute is handled differently. Im trying to figure out how...